# how make include import in flex/bison

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I'm making a programming language converter and, and it has import and include.

For example:

```
 import com.nanana.MyClassFile
 include "myfile.any"
```

I'm newbie which means I'm lost in how can I make it.
I wondering if is possible parse another file while one is been parsing.

And how can I do it?

EDIT:

The code I'm using to parse files in main function is:

```
yyin = fopen( argv[1], "r" ); 
return yyparse();
```

Can I use this same code, or there is another?

Answer (score 1):

The lexer uses the YY_INPUT macro to obtain its data. Within the parser, once the include "myfile.any" command has been parsed, the parser will need to open up the new file and arrange that its data will be returned from YY_INPUT, instead of the original file. Once EOF has been reached, then YY_INPUT will need to continue reading from the original file. You'll probably want to store those open files on a stack so that included files can in turn include other files, but watch out for an infinite include loop.

Comment: As I said, I'm newbie, I hope a little more deep and exemplified answer. Please. thx.

Comment: The exact solution is going to be highly dependent on your specific parser/lexer; this isn't really the appropriate forum to get into that kind of detail. The idea is to use YY_INPUT to feed data one character at a time into the lexer. The parser will control from which file those characters come. Take a look at the generated code to see how all this ties together. There are a few entries in the flex FAQ that touch peripherally on this topic (such as How can I have multiple input sources feed into the same scanner at the same time?)